# How to reuse EventListener if it already exists? [plain JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, event-listener, reusability

I have function **A** with `addEventListener` **#1** on HTML element. It does some work and executing some functions. Further in code there is other **B** function with `addEventListener` **#2**, which does some other work. 
Both `EventListener`s are at **change** "mode".

It works but i noticed that when i execute function **A**, it properly works and it executes again **B** function with it's `addEventListener` **#2**. So then i have got two (or more - depends on how many times I use **#1** listener) **#2** `EventListeners` (in **B** function).

**JavaScriptCode** (simplified):

```
var a = document.getElementById('firstSelect'),
    b = document.getElementById('secondSelect');

 (function()
 {
          function parent()
         {
                a.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
                {
                    alert(ev.target.innerHTML);

                  kid();
                }, false);
         };
         parent();

         function kid()
         {
                b.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
              {             
                alert(ev.target.innerHTML);

              }, false);

         } 
 }());
```

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/Chriss92/u4yrypug/

In Chrome it looks like this - when click (use) **#1** `EventListener` more than once, it's adding one **#2** `EventListener`, so then when I use **#2** it executes it's code many times (as it's created or added many times) :

*First* use of **#1** `EventListener`

[image]

*Second* use of **#1** `EventListener`

[image]

... and when i click five times on **#1** `EventListener` it adds five **#2** `EventListener`s:

[image]

And so on, more times i click on **#1** `EventListener`, more **#2** `EventListener` is added.

---

**My QUESTION is:** how to **REUSE** `EventListener` instead of adding it, when it's created already? I want clean JavaScript solution, not jQuery, please.

Comment: Its a bit confusing. Also add code how you are assigning eventlistener

Comment: Look up how you remove event listeners. Just as you can add event listeners you can remove them from DOM elements as well. So it seems to me that you need to manage when an event listener added to an element and when not.

Comment: If you're adding two listeners to the same element, then that's the problem. You should use N functions for the same event on the same element rather than N listeners to the same event.

Comment: I added code and JSFiddle demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = document.getElementById('firstSelect'),
b = document.getElementById('secondSelect');

(function()
 {
      function parent()
     {
            a.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
            {
                alert(ev.target.innerHTML);

              kid();
            }, false);
     };
     parent();


     function kid()
     {
        b.removeEventListener('change', kid_handler, false);
            b.addEventListener('change', kid_handler, false);
     } 

     function kid_handler(ev){
        alert(ev.target.innerHTML);
     }
 }());
```

Comment: Thank you for simple and reusable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a counter approach if you must add event listeners inside another event. The event will not be added unless the counter for the event equals zero.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/YwaYWM

```
var a = document.getElementById('firstSelect'),
b = document.getElementById('secondSelect');

//counters for each elements event
var aCount = 0, bCount = 0;

 (function()
 {
          function parent()
         {

       //if the counter equals 0
       if(aCount === 0){//begin if then

                a.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
                {
                    alert(ev.target.innerHTML);

                  kid();
                }, false);

         //increment the counter
       aCount++;

       }//end if then


         };
         parent();

         function kid()
         {

       //if the counter equals 0
       if(bCount === 0){//begin if then

                b.addEventListener('change', function(ev)
              {             
                alert(ev.target.innerHTML);

              }, false);

         //increment the counter
         bCount++;

       }//end if then

         } 
 }())
```

;

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two general approaches:

1. [HTMLElement.onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) - you can replace event listener every time you are calling `kid` function. It's not a good solution in a general way, because there could be other modules which could add their `onchange` event listeners. But if it's OK with you system, this will work.
2. You could add some state behavior. That is you just set some `isInitialized` variable to `true` in the first call of `parent` and `kid` functions, and then you check it in the next time. If it's `false`, then add an event listener.